# What is the most efficient way to generate a serie from a recurrence relation in Python using pandas and numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using pandas and numpy, what is the most efficient way to do what the `f1` function does?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time

n = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["a"] = np.random.randn(n)
df["b"] = np.random.uniform(n)


def f1(df):
    df.loc[0, "c"] = 100
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        df.loc[i, "c"] = df.loc[i, "a"] * df.loc[i, "b"] +\
            (1 - df.loc[i, "a"]) * df.loc[i - 1, "c"]

start_time = time()
f1(df)
ellapsed_time = time() - start_time
print(ellapsed_time)
```

Comment: What do you want `f1` does?Do you really want `i` to be the index of `df`?

Comment: Instead of using `for` with `range`. `iteriterms()` is a good option.

Comment: Hello Shihe, no I do not really need `i` to be the index but how would you write f1 with `iteritems`? I had tried with `iterrows` but it had not been an improvement.

Comment: Maybe try cython?

Comment: Yes ags29, I will turn to Cython if there is no efficient solution with numpy/pandas :)

Comment: iterrows converts rows to series and so should be slow. have you tried itertuples instead? Look at piRSquared's answer here: [Iterate Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas). Also, you may want to try numba first before Cython to bring in the power of JIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `scipy.signal` can solve such recurence, but I do not find a good solution here. The Numba workaround :

```
import numba
@numba.njit
def f1n(a,b):
    c=np.empty_like(a)
    c[0]=100
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        c[i]=a[i]*b[i]+(1-a[i])*c[i-1]
    return c
```

Tests:

```
In [559]: %timeit f1n(df.a.values,df.b.values)
52.9 µs ± 1.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [560]: %timeit f1(df)
4.62 s ± 13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [563]: np.allclose(df.c,f1n(df.a.values,df.b.values))
Out[563]: True
```

90,000 x faster, and equally readable.